# Understanding ergodic capacity: how to prove : two channels c1, c2 - capacities, but we do not know what channel has c1, what c2 nevertheless capacity is c1+c2 

Tags: it.information-theory

As far as I understand if we have channel which has random capacity for each discrete time moment (for example Rayleigh fading ), then

**the capacity is just average capacity.**

I am trying to understand it.

It seems the following simpliefied situation should be understand first:
consider the two channels assume we know that capacity of one of them is c1 , capacity of another is c2, but we do not know what channel has c1, what channel has c2.
Nevetheless it seems that capacity is c1+c2, the same as as if we know what channel has c1, what channel has c2...

For example if we consider AWGN channels - can one suggest some simple proof of this ?

(Similar to proof of capacity for AWGN with balls filling )

Answer (score 2):

I recommend O. Sarig, *Lecture Notes on Ergodic Theory*, Dec., 2009, available [here](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~sarigo/506/ErgodicNotes.pdf). Chapter 2 is about Ergodic Theorems.

Another interesting reference is P. Billingsley, *Ergodic Theory and Information*, John Wiley & Sons, 1965. For example, Chapter 5, Section 16 (The noisy channel) have a subsection about channel capacity and ergodicity of the input-output process.